# Parameterize an element in a record that is used in a port

Tags: parameters, vhdl, record, hdl

What is the best way to parameterize an element of a record?

For example:

I have this component:

```
component C1 is
port (
  clk               : in  std_logic;
  reset_n           : in  std_logic; 
  cam               : out t_CAM_OUT
);
end component C1;
```

The type `t_CAM_OUT` is defined in a package:

```
package camera_signals_pkg is

  -- Output signals related to camera
  type t_CAM_OUT is record
    ...
    pixel_data      : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    ...
  end record t_CAM_OUT;

end package camera_signals_pkg;
```

I want to however parameterise the signal *pixel_data*

In one instantiation of component *C1* I require *pixel_data* to be 16 bits and in another instantiation it must be 32 bits.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: In VHDL -2008 there are numerous ways. Instantiate a generic package (a primary unit),  Reference a context declaration as a context item, a generic type with the record subtype passed,  Tricky's subtype indication providing the record subtype, The ability to use any of these can depend on -2008 feature support in an entire tool chain, for example when doing mixed language simulation or synthesis.  Best in terms of what? We can see from the two answers so far you're soliciting opinions.

Comment: I find it a little challenging to find all the ways one can do this and then pick the best way to do it. I lean on StackOverflow to learn how others resolve the same type of issue I have. Is there any reference/documentation you can recommend?

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to use VHDL 2008, you can simply leave `pixel_data` unconstrained in the type, and then constrain it during the port declaration, either from a literal per entity, or from a generic, like you would any type.

```
-- Output signals related to camera
  type t_CAM_OUT is record
    ...
    pixel_data      : std_logic_vector;
    ...
  end record t_CAM_OUT;
```

```
entity ent1 is
port (
  clk               : in  std_logic;
  reset_n           : in  std_logic; 
  cam               : out t_CAM_OUT( pixel_data(15 downto 0) );
);
```

```
entity generic_ent is
generic (
  W : natural
);
port(
  clk               : in  std_logic;
  reset_n           : in  std_logic; 
  cam               : out t_CAM_OUT( pixel_data(W-1 downto 0) );
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I implemented this method and seems to be the most elegant way I have seen so far. I've had no synthesis issues with this technique. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The way I've often done this is to serialize the data at the module's port level, and serialize it from its record type to `std_logic_vector` inside your architecture (or deserialize it from an `std_logic_vector` back into a record in case of an input port).

I.e. the component would become:

```
component C1 is
  generic (
    g_cam_length : positive
  );
  port (
    clk     : in  std_logic;
    reset_n : in  std_logic; 
    cam     : out std_logic_vector(f_CAM_OUT_length(g_cam_length) - 1 downto 0)
  );
end component C1;

architecture RTL of C1 is
  type t_CAM_OUT is record
    pixel_data : std_logic_vector(g_pixel_length - 1 downto 0);
  end record t_CAM_OUT;

  function to_slv (data : t_CAM_OUT) return std_logic_vector is
    variable result : std_logic_vector(f_CAM_OUT_length(g_cam_length - 1) downto 0);
  begin
    ...
  end function to_slv;
begin
end architecture RTL;
```

So you would have a function `f_CAM_OUT_length` in a package, which helps calculate the length of the serialized `t_CAM_OUT` record.

Depending on how your design is structured, this is not really ideal, because it creates quite a bit of coupling between different modules and packages.

Of course, this means that you can't define your record in a package. I.e. you'll have to define your record inside your module architecture.

*Edit:* Removed part of answer about generic packages in VHDL-2008, since the don't work for this particular problem.

Comment: Package generics seems overkill, you can simply leave the type unconstrained and constrain it in the entity. Not all tools support package generics, while most have supported unconstrained types for quite some time. Because of this, I now only use serialisation when Im forced to (like connecting a record type into a generic FIFO).

Comment: Also, your example shows a pacakage as a generic, but incorrectly mapped. The package instantiated has to be in a declarative region, and then the package maped as any other generic. Packages as generics have seen very little support even from sim vendors until recently.

Comment: To whoever downvoted me, please explain why. My answer shows one possible solution which works (and has been used in the design of some very large ones >100M gate ASICs).

Comment: @Tricky Can you give an example of how the package should be instantiated using the component's generics? As I noted, I've never used this due to lack of tooling support.

Comment: @Tricky Those unconstrained records seems like a very nice solution indeed! I'll definitely try to push that through synthesis and formal verification next time I need something like it.

Comment: While it shows the serialisation solution, the second example code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do need it to be in a package. I haven't been able to correctly implement the package generics method yet, it gets convoluted really fast. A quick implementation has thrown some errors, I'll need to spend more time on it and check if it compiles.

Comment: @Tricky I realize that now. However, I can't seem to find an example of the correct syntax. Hence my question if you can point me to the correct syntax. That would allow me to improve my answer.

Comment: @surabhig Yeah, if you need it to be in a package then this won't work. Tricky's solution does look very nice.

Comment: @Darhuuk Heres an example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6Mpm

Comment: @Tricky Thanks! It looks like that syntax isn't able to solve this particular problem, since there seems to be no way to get the entity's generic value into the package's generic mapping.

Comment: I dont know why you would want to, when unconstrained types solve the OPs problem.

Comment: @Tricky I wasn't aware that unconstrained records like that were possible. It's definitely the perfect solution here. Updating my answer to remove the suggestion for generic packages.